# Can I make an HTTP post from Azure Mobile Services Script scheduler?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using the new scheduler service within Windows Azure Moblie Services.  I wanted to know if I can do an HTTP post from the script?

Here is my scenario:  I have built a service that goes out and does some logic and updates my database with the results.  In a certain condition, I would like it to notify me via SMS text message.  =>  Enter Twilio.

Twilio has a RESTful api for me to communicate with cellphones via a simple HTTP POST.  How can I generate the HTTP post from the script within the scheduler to post (something) to an external API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had a management website already on AZURE anyway, I just wrote a custom handler passing the data and then using the extremely easy-to-use Twilio .NET Rest api:

- Created an (Notify.ashx) http handler
- Downloaded the Twilio Rest API helper library
- Added the following code to my handler

  ```
  Dim twilio = New TwilioRestClient(myAccountSid, myAuthToken)
  Dim twilio_message = twilio.SendSmsMessage(FromTwilioPhone, ToCellphone, message)
  ```
- Added this to my Server Script:

  ```
  function notify(uniqueident) {
      var url = "http://{mywebsite}.azurewebsites.net/Notify.ashx?id=" + uniqueident;

      request(url, function siteLoaded (error, response, body) {
                  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                      console.log('Notification sent: ' + uniqueident);
                  } else { 
                      console.error('Could not contact azure.');
                  }
      });
  }
  ```

What would be really nice is that if WindowsAzure had a add-on (app service) for Twilio like #SendGrid.  (hint... hint...)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way it to use [Twilio Module for nodejs](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html).

[Blog post](http://www.tapanila.net/creating-twitter-reader-using-windows-azure-mobile-services/) how to use modules on your server side script.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Heres some Azure documentation on using Twilios node.js library with Mobile Services:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/twilio-for-voice-and-sms/

Hope that helps.